# Carbon addWeeks() function not working

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I am creating some dates with Carbon in PHP, but I seem to be doing something wrong.

This here is my code:

```
$start = Carbon::create(2015, rand(6,7), rand(1,30), 0);
$end = $start->addWeeks(3);

echo "start time: " . $start;
echo "<br />";
echo "end time: " . $end;
```

And the output of the above is two exact same dates, e.g.:

```
start time: 2015-07-01 00:00:00
end time: 2015-07-01 00:00:00
```

I reffered to the docs, which can be found here: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub.
Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are those carbon object mutable or not? If yes you might be printing the same twice. `addWeeks()` might return `$start` (modified) for method chaining. Thus `$start === $end`

Comment: Does `addWeek()` work? I'd test myself, but don't have access to Carbon. Also, I'd confirm if the PHP version is sufficient and any dependencies are up-to-date.The home page says *1.x is compatible with PHP 5.3+. A 2.x version is in the works and will require PHP 5.4+.*

Comment: @YiminRong server is configured fine, I am using Laravel on a vm with PHP 5.6

Comment: You can try moving `echo "start time: " . $start;` to before the `addWeeks` line. This will tell you whether the operation succeeded. It might be that some Carbon functions modify the caller, as opposed to returning a new object. Some of the PHP array functions do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't worked with Carbon yet but I'd say those Carbon object are mutable. Also most functions seem to return `$this` for method chaining (aka *fluent interface*).

Thus, when doing `$end = $start->addWeeks(3);` your `$end` is actually the same object as `$start`. (just an intelligent guess)

To avoid this try to either `clone` the object before manipulation (if possible) or create another one.

Version 1

```
$start = Carbon::create(2015, rand(6,7), rand(1,30), 0);
$end = clone $start;
$start->addWeeks(3);
```

Version 2

```
$start = Carbon::create(2015, rand(6,7), rand(1,30), 0);
$end = Carbon::create(2015, rand(6,7), rand(1,30), 0);
$start->addWeeks(3);
```

Comment: yep, you were right, the objects are mutable and your intelligent guess was correct, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

$end takes the same value as $start after the addition and it looks like it has not changed. But it has:

```
>>> use Carbon\Carbon;
=> false
>>> $start = Carbon::create(2015, rand(6,7), rand(1,30), 0);
=> Carbon\Carbon {#766
     +"date": "2015-07-16 00:00:00",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "Asia/Bangkok",
   }
>>> $end = $start->addWeeks(3);
=> Carbon\Carbon {#766
     +"date": "2015-08-06 00:00:00",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "Asia/Bangkok",
   }
>>> $end
=> Carbon\Carbon {#766
     +"date": "2015-08-06 00:00:00",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "Asia/Bangkok",
   }
>>> $start
=> Carbon\Carbon {#766
     +"date": "2015-08-06 00:00:00",
     +"timezone_type": 3,
     +"timezone": "Asia/Bangkok",
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Carbon dates *are* mutable.  Try this:

```
$rand_date = Carbon::create(2015, rand(6,7), rand(1,30), 0);


echo "start time: " . $rand_date->format('Y-m-d');
echo "<br />";
echo "end time: " . $rand_date->addWeeks(3)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

because you'r not parsing date ($start) in carbon parse method,

```
$start = Carbon::create(2015, rand(6,7), rand(1,30), 0);
$end = Carbon::parse($start)->addWeeks(3);
```

i have not tested your code but hope so it work.